# Open SSL Communication TimeOut Error using SSL_CTX_set_timeout

Tags: c, openssl

I am using Open SSL Communication for Server-Client communication.It is working fine,but session timeout SSL_CTX_set_timeout method is not working.

### Below is the Code:

```
 SSL_CTX *ctx;
 OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms(); 
 if(SSL_library_init() != 1){
 return -1; 
}
 SSL_load_error_strings();
 meth = SSLv3_method(); 
 ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth); 
 SSL_CTX_set_timeout(ctx, 180);
```

Here SSL_CTX_set_timeout is not working even when the server does not send any message to client for more than 5 min.

Kindly advice me to solve the issue.

Thanks in Advance
Prakash B

Answer (score 2):

`SSL_CTX_set_timeout()` only sets the [session expiration timeout](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_timeout.html) (when to renegotiate SSL/TLS), not some kind of communication timeout. You are expected to deal with the latter in your socket management code.

Comment: isn't there a timeout for ssl handshake ?

Comment: Do you mean the socket level?